# maven-assembly-plugin doesn't add target/class artifacts in generated jarfat but META-INF/MANIFEST.MF seems to be correct

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

The maven-assembly-plugin doesn't add target/class artifacts in generated fatjar but META-INF/MANIFEST.MF seems to be correct. I'm using the `3.4.0` plugin version.

See below the relevant build segment extracted from pom.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        <mainClass>my_package.Main</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

this command below does not show anything

```bash
jar -tvf target/my-fat-jar.jar | grep Main.class
```

My main class and other project artifacts are not added in fatjar by `maven-assembly-plugin`

**Edit:** I tested it with other versions of the plugin (`3.2.0, 2.2, ...`) and it didn't work. However if I change the version from `3.4.0` to `2.2-beta-5` the fatjar is generated correctly. Version `2.2-beta-5` is from 12/06/2009, ie very old. I would like to use a newer version. Any idea ?

Comment: Please show the full pom file....

Comment: It would also being very helpful to have a full example project on github or alike.